# if data needed to be trim before going database which tier do you put it in

Tags: hibernate, jsf

all data is required to be trimmed before going database. i currently use hibernate with JSF.
where would you put this logic in? in hibernate entity bean,or JSF backing beans?
what's pros and cons. is there any other suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in the view side. You can just create a JSF [`Converter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) for [`String.class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class)
public class StringTrimmer implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return value.trim();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

}
```

Or when you're still on JSF 1.2, get rid of [`@FacesConverter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/FacesConverter.html) and register it as follows in your `faces-config.xml`.

```
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>java.lang.String</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>com.example.converters.StringTrimmer</converter-class>
</converter>
```

Either way, it'll be applied on all input properties of the `String` type without the need to change anything else.

This is not possible on JSF 1.1 or older due to the internal design.

Comment: i appreciate the answer. i have tried other suggestions. this works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reason to have the data untrimmed anywhere in the application, I would trim it at the point of data entry.  This saves you the need to remember to trim values in different areas of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I'll disagree with the other answers on this. I had the same situation in a project, and our solution was to create a custom Hibernate mapping, called "TrimmedString", which we applied by default to all String properties in the project. This proved better than applying this logic to any part of our application, because it's not really in its concern to trim the data (it's plumbing code, not business). Also, applying it directly as a Hibernate avoids problems if you have two ways of getting data into your system (Web UI and WebService, for instance).